# Custom JPEG image handling in Delphi

Tags: delphi, graphics, firemonkey

We use Delphi XE6 to build a cross-platform FireMonkey app and we want to tweak a little the JPG encoder. 
In fact we want to subclass it, to change the JPEG signature, add some parameters in file and change the file extension. Nothing will be changed in the actual JPEG engine.

Also, we want to support the `LoadThumbnailFromFile` which will still use the actual JPG code.

However we have a hard time to find where in the world is declared in source the JPG encoder and how to subclass/derive it.

Comment: @bummi: that is the way the VCL handles graphics. That is not the way FireMonkey handles graphics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way FireMonkey handles graphics is vastly different than how VCL handles graphics.

In VCL, graphics are handled using specialized classes derived from [`Vcl.Graphics.TGraphic`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Graphics.TGraphic), such as [`Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap) and [`Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage).  You create a specific class when you want to load/save a specific graphic type.

In FireMonkey, graphics are handled using specialized classes derived from [`FMX.Graphics.TCustomBitmapCodec`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Graphics.TCustomBitmapCodec) that are registered with the [`FMX.Graphics.TBitmapCodecManager`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmapCodecManager) class.  You use the general-purpose [`FMX.Graphics.TBitmap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap) class for handling all graphics.  When loading a graphic, it uses the appropriate registered codec (if it can find one), but when saving you have to specify the codec you want to use.

FireMonkey uses different codec implementations for each platform, thus there is no single class that you can subclass, like there is in VCL.  So, in order to customize JPEG handling in FireMonkey, you will have to create your own `TCustomBitmapCodec`-derived codec and register it with `TBitmapCodecManager` (unregistering the existing classes for the `.jpg` and `.jpeg` file extensions).  Here are the codec classes that FireMonkey currently implements:

1. Windows: `TBitmapCodecWIC` in `FMX.Canvas.D2D.pas`
2. OSX: `TBitmapCodecQuartz` in `FMX.Canvas.Mac.pas`
3. iOS: `TBitmapCodecQuartz` in `FMX.Canvas.iOS.pas`
4. Android: `TBitmapCodecAndroid` in `FMX.Canvas.Android.pas`

Using `{$IFDEF}` statements, you might be able to utilize those existing classes inside of your custom codec as needed.